# Using arc4random on Ubuntu 14.04 trusty

Tags: compiling, c++, libraries

I am currently working with a C++ program where I wish to use arc4random function. Every time I compile, I receive a not declared in scope message for arc4random. I understand that this is an error in my included libraries in my program, and yet I have included both stdlib.h and stdio.h which I believe are the libraries it uses? I have installed 'sudo apt-get install libpcl-all', as well as, 'sudo apt-get install build-essential'. I have scoured the web, but am still unsure what I need at this point. I am still very new at Ubuntu, so any help with this problem would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `arc4random` function is a BSD utility that is not part of the standard C library on Ubuntu. To use it, I think that you will need to install the `libbsd-dev` package, and then include the BSD version of the header explicitly using

```cpp
#include <bsd/stdlib.h>
```

You will then need to link your executable with the `libbsd` library by adding `-lbsd` to your compiler command line, for example

```
g++ -o prog -Wall prog.cpp -lbsd
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I installed libbsd-dev using the command line(i.e.  sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libbsd-dev)
And I added #include <bsd/stdlib.h> to a simple test program.
And I added -lbsd to the C++ compile commands on the compiler program I am using(I am using Geany) to produce a simple line of code as follows:

Comment: using namespace std;

#include <iostream>
#include <bsd/stdlib.h>

int main()
{
 int x = arc4random();
 cout << x;
 return 0;
}
Unfortunately, I still get an error message that says
g++ -Wall -o "Arc4randTest1" "Arc4randTest1.cxx" (in directory: /home/jmickey/C++ Projects1)
/tmp/ccx5ZPNn.o: In function `main':
Arc4randTest1.cxx:(.text+0x9): undefined reference to `arc4random'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Compilation failed.
I am sorry if I am being very dense, but I am rather new to Ubuntu and am not extremely advanced in C++ either.

Comment: Your first comment says you added `-lbsd` but I don't see it in your second comment - the command needs to be `g++ -Wall -o Arc4randTest1 Arc4randTest1.cxx -lbsd`. [ASIDE: it's horrible to read code in comments - better to edit your question instead]

Comment: Sorry, next time I will put my code above. This worked; I just put the -lbsd in the wrong place for my compiler program. Thank you so much :)